# How can I add an accordion?

Tags: webforms, 9

I would like to create an accordion using the Drupal 9 webform.
Any suggestions on how it should be done? Thanks
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When adding a webform component, look in the Containers section and add a "Details" container to your form. This should give you an accordion-like behavior using HTML5 details/summary elements.